# Avoiding cartesian product with Django

Tags: python, sql, django, cartesian-product, cross-join

I have the following three tables defined.

```py
class Operator(models.Model):
    DisplayName = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Experiment"
        db_table = "EXPERIMENT_OPERATOR"

class OperatorSummary(models.Model):
    Operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator, related_name="TransactionSummary")
    TransactionCount = models.IntegerField()
    TransactionValue = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2)
    StartTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Experiment"
        db_table = "EXPERIMENT_OPERATORSUMMARY"

class OperatorAlerts(models.Model):
    Operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator, related_name="AlertSummary")
    AlertScore = models.IntegerField()
    AlertCount = models.IntegerField()
    StartTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

    class Meta:
        app_label = "Experiment"
        db_table = "EXPERIMENT_OPERATORALERTS"
```

For an `Operator`, I would like to retrieve the `AlertScore` and the `TransactionCount` for a given date range. The query I'm using looks like this:

```py
tz = timezone.get_default_timezone()    
vs = Operator.objects.filter(DisplayName="Jimmy",
                             TransactionSummary__StartTime__gte=tz.localize(datetime(year=2013, month=10, day=1)),
                             AlertSummary__StartTime__gte=tz.localize(datetime(year=2013, month=10, day=1)))\
    .annotate(TotalTransactions=Sum("TransactionSummary__TransactionCount"),
              TotalAlerts=Sum("AlertSummary__AlertScore"))\
    .values("DisplayName", "TransactionSummary__TransactionCount", "AlertSummary__AlertScore")
```

This query performs a cartesian product and returns all the rows in the `OperatorAlerts` and `OperatorSummary` table that match the query. This is what it returns:

```
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 20, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 10}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 44, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 10}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 543, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 10}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 20, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 22}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 44, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 22}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 543, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 22}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 20, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 234}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 44, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 234}
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 543, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 234}
```

I'd like to fix this so that I get the following result:

```
{'AlertSummary__AlertScore': 607, 'DisplayName': u'Jimmy', 'TransactionSummary__TransactionCount': 266}
```

All the results are collapsed into one row where the `AlertScore` and `TransactionCount` are summed.

Is that possible? I can always fall back to making a separate query for the `OperatorAlerts` and `OperatorSummary` and then iterating over the result set in Python to get the results I want or calling `.aggregate`, but I'm sure there must be a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing the order in which you apply the `values()` and `annotate()` methods. `values()` should come first:

```
vs = Operator.objects.filter(DisplayName="Jimmy",
                             TransactionSummary__StartTime__gte=tz.localize(datetime(year=2013, month=10, day=1)),
                             AlertSummary__StartTime__gte=tz.localize(datetime(year=2013, month=10, day=1)))\
    .values("DisplayName")\
    .annotate(TotalTransactions=Sum("TransactionSummary__TransactionCount"),
              TotalAlerts=Sum("AlertSummary__AlertScore"))
```

This will group the results by fields mentioned in `values()` and then generate an annotation for each group. The order is very significant - [as documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses).

Applying `values()` and `annotate()` in the way you do (i.e. `annotate()` before `values()`) will generate annotations for every item separately.

Please note that the code above will group the results by `DisplayName`. You may want to group by a different field, for example `pk`.

Also, I assume that in your real code you will want to get the values for multiple operators at once. If you always queried for one operator at a time (like you do in your example) you would be better of using `aggregate()` instead of `annotate()`.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. You are correct that I would like to query for multiple operators at once. However, I `annotate` is still what I need as I would like `TotalTransactions` and `TotalAlerts` to be for each user, and not an aggregate over all users.

Comment: I agree, that's exactly what I meant. I think the sentence was a little confusing, because I used a wrong grammatical form. I corrected it now.